# Why this class constructor raises this error?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, constructor, frozenset

Having this class:

```
class A(frozenset):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        frozenset.__init__(self, *args)
```

Executing `A(range(2))` results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#65>", line 1, in <module>
    A(range(2))
  File "<pyshell#60>", line 3, in __init__
    frozenset.__init__(self, *args)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

Meanwhile, `frozenset(range(2))` works, and if I inherit `A` from `set` instead, `A(range(2))` also works.

If I pass to A's constructor 0 or more than 1 parameter, it works as it should (with 0 paramemeters creates an empty set, with 2 or more parameters raises `TypeError: A expected at most 1 arguments, got 2`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you need to override `__new__` method (not `__init__`, `__init__` method will accept an instance generated and returned by `__new__` method) when subclassing `frozenset` to create a new *frozenset* from a passed iterable (as argument):

```
class A(frozenset):
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        self = super().__new__(cls, *args)
        return self


print(A(range(2)))
print(A(range(2)).__class__.__bases__)
```

Sample output:

```
A({0, 1})
(<class 'frozenset'>,)
```

Comment: why is the behaviour different for `set`?

Comment: `__init__` doesn't create a value; it *initializes* it *after* it has been created. Sets are mutable, and so can be initialized. Frozen sets are *not* mutable, so you need to pass the initial contents to the actual constructor (`__new__`), not the initializer.